# Datagridivew column header date format reverse

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, header, col

I am using vb.net with a `datagridview` tied to a crosstab query with 31 columns, where the headers are dates!.

The column header are all dates in the format `2001-12-01`.

I wish to show the column headers as `01-12-2001`

Here is my vb.net code to do it, but is there a simpler way?

When the Form Shown event is run I then manually reverse the headers using string concatenation!

```
Private Sub FrmClientActivity_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        'Reverse Column Headers
        Dim c As Integer
        Dim txt As String

        For c = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2
            'MsgBox(c)
            txt = Me.DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderCell.Value.ToString()
            txt = Mid(txt, 9, 2) & "-" & Mid(txt, 6, 2) & "-" & Mid(txt, 1, 4)
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderCell.Value = txt  
        Next c

End Sub
```

Also tried this but didn't work either

```
 Me.DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderCell.Style.Format = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

All help appreciated

Comment: Try `DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderText = Date.Parse(DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderText).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Comment: Or, if the `HeaderCell.Value` is actually DateTime, `DataGridView1.Columns(c0).HeaderText = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderCell.Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`.

Comment: Hi Jimi that worked a treat, so I was able to do away with the txt string and contcatenation!